# Is there a way to pass HTML code in flask as string?

Tags: python, html, string, flask

Is there a way to pass HTML code as a string in python/flask rather than render template HTML file in a directory?

for example

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('index.html') # Instead of giving file path I want to pass HTML code directly 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: `return '<HTML...>'`…? Any issue when you do that?

Comment: `return "<p>hello world</p>"` ? There are many ways; you can save your html strings in database and read html strings from database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


HTML_AS_TEXT = """<p>hello world</p>"""

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return HTML_AS_TEXT

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```